# vim move tab to end of all other tabs

Tags: vim, tabs, move

Is there way in vim to move a tab to the end (to the right) of all other tabs without having to count how many tabs there are and entering that number?

Some times I have lots of tabs open, and tmux panes open. I dont want to have to zoom into the vim window, count the number of tabs, then `:tabm n`.

Comment: If you know `:tabm`, then you know where and how to find the information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on checking tabm documentation, I read it before it was just not clear to me.

Comment: You should make it an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out. its `tabm $`

from documentation

```
:tabm[ove] [N]                      :tabm :tabmove
:[N]tabm[ove]
        Move the current tab page to after tab page N.  Use zero to
        make the current tab page the first one.  N is counted before
        the move, thus if the second tab is the current one,
        `:tabmove 1` and `:tabmove 2`  have no effect.
        Without N the tab page is made the last one. 
            :.tabmove   " do nothing
            :-tabmove   " move the tab page to the left
            :+tabmove   " move the tab page to the right
            :0tabmove   " move the tab page to the beginning of the tab
                " list
            :tabmove 0  " as above
            :tabmove    " move the tab page to the last
            :$tabmove   " as above
            :tabmove $  " as above
            :tabmove #  " move the tab page after the last accessed
                " tab page
```